# JBoss Tools - Allow remote access to localhost:8080

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I'm working on Eclipse 3.5 with JBoss Tools, and even though I remember doing it before, I haven't been able to make my JBoss running instance from Eclipse available to other computers on the network.

If I try to change the program arguments:

```
-b localhost
```

The program reports:

> The Host can only be changed in the
>   Server Editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, that was dumb from me.

**[Solution]**: Change the **Host Name** on the **Server Edition** (that's the view you get when you double click on your JBoss instance on the Servers view). If you enter "0.0.0.0" as the host name, that will make JBoss listen on all network interfaces. 
Nevermind...

Answer (score 0):

Double click on server>JBoss, then add Host name: 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost, if you configure the jBoss like this, you can access anywhere in the network.
[Figure: JBoss Settings](https://goo.gl/photos/xFtFG38cpWqqcw5v8)

Comment: isn't this redundant to the existing answer?

Comment: Yes it is. but with more details for beginners.